# Incorrect file format 'user'

Tags: mysql

Я установил БД на RPI
Но когда я пытаюсь создать нового юзера

> sudo mysql --user=root --password

> create user admin@localhost identified by 'your_password';

Я получаю ошибку

> Incorrect file format 'user'

Как это исправить?

Comment: а если просто sudo mysql -u root ?

Comment: очень странно, только что проверил у себя на малине - команда работает как нужно. может вы при наборе ошиблись?

Comment: На другой малине у меня все поднялось без проблем. Но на ней после не захотел вставать python-serial. На малине где я получаю ошибку я наоборот первым установил python-serial, теперь не могу поднять БД. Больше различий нет

Comment: *Но когда я пытаюсь создать нового юзера* Показанная команда `sudo mysql --user=root --password` не имеет никакого отношения к созданию юзера. Эта команда запускает клиента командной строки. А сообщение об ошибке - оно вряд ли MySQL-евское...

Comment: @Akina ох, я забыл добавить ещё одну строчку которую я пытаюсь выполнить. Я обновил пост

Comment: [Specifying Account Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html), [CREATE USER Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html). Читать ОЧЕНЬ внимательно, обращая внимание на КАЖДЫЙ символ.